# SQL Oracle output from table after stored procedures

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddInterest 
( bankname VARCHAR, rate DECIMAL) 
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE Deposit SET balance = balance + (balance * rate / 100) 
WHERE branchname = bankname;

**dbms_output.put_line(bankname ||rate );**
END;
/
```

in my code, the dbms_output,
I want to output what i have edited from the deposit account. 
Please help.

Comment: Do you want to add an `out` parameter to the stored procedure?  You could do that though, presumably, you wouldn't return to the caller a string that just combines the data in the two input parameters...

Comment: Look up [RETURNING BULK COLLECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) syntax for Oracle

Comment: An [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#BABHDFDE) is the perfect example with the dbms_output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable `UpdatedRecords` of `TABLE OF Deposit%ROWTYPE` and add `RETURNING BULK COLLECT`-clause to your `UPDATE` statement.

`UPDATE ...
RETURNING <all fields> BULK COLLECT INTO UpdatedRecords;`

After the execution `UpdatedRecords` variable will be a collection of updated records as they were looking before changes. Scan it with `LOOP` and print what ever you want.

You can also reduce a number of fields collected after the executeion, just change `RETURNING` clause and give the proper declaration for `UpdatedRecords` variable.

Refer to Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354 for `RETUNING` clause.